# hiding case, until parameters are met

Tags: java, switch-statement

I am trying to write a weather condition model.  I am having issues with the switch/case.  I want one of my cases not available unit two variable are filled by the user.  How would I do this?  Here is the code clip

```
 switch (choice) {
            case 0:
                System.out.println("Exit");
                break;
            case 1:

                int yInch = in.nextInt();
                yester = CondYest(yInch);

                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("Enter/Update Today's Weather Prediction");
                int tInch = in.nextInt();
                today = CondToday(tInch);
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("Display Snow Prediction");
                System.out.println("Today's Snow Fall is " + today + " inches!");
                System.out.println("Yesterday's Snow Fall was " + yester + " inches!");
                System.out.println();
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Please Try again");
                break;
        }
    } while (choice != 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

The "beginner level" answer is: have multiple switch statements.

In other words: a "controller" component understands which different "menus" exist, and which pre-conditions need to be met to make that decision.

To turn it into a real world solution, you probably would want to use polymorphism here. Like: having a base class that provides say a `showMenu()` method which displays choices and asks for the required input. That class also has (abstract) methods for having different behavior.

And then you add multiple child classes that @Override these base methods as needed.

Finally, your controller then "only" has to determine which class to instantiate in order to show the currently valid selections.